# Bundling Vendor Files Using Gulp

Tags: gulp, syntax-error

I am trying to split my source code from vendor using `gulp`. At the current state, this is how my `gulpfile.js` is setup:

`gulpfile.js`

```
/////////////       LIBS        \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var superstatic = require('superstatic');
var gulpTsc = require('gulp-typescript');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var tsConfigGlob = require('tsconfig-glob');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var path = require('path');
var child_process = require('child_process');
var del = require('del');
var sourceStream = require('vinyl-source-stream');

// other tasks

var bundleVendorFiles = function(done) {
var deps = Object.keys(ngPkgFile && ngPkgFile.dependencies || {});
deps.map(d => {
    let posOfAt = d.indexOf('@'),
        modName = `${angularAppLocation}/node_modules/`,
        exposeName = d;
    if(posOfAt < 0) modName += d;
    else modName += `@angular/${d.split('/').pop()}`;
    return {
        file: modName,
        expose: exposeName
    };    
});
browserify({
    paths: [angularAppLocation+'/node_modules'],
    basedir: '/home/zerocool/srs-demo/loginapp'
})
    .require(deps)
    .transform("babelify", { presets: ["es2015"]})
    .bundle()
    .pipe(sourceStream('vendor.bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(angularAppLocation+'/dist'));
done();
};

gulp.task('default', gulp.series([
'clean-dist-dir', 'copy-index-file', 'expand-file-glob',
'ts-compile', 'bundle-vendor-pkgs',/*
'copy-static-assets', 'copy-misc-asset-files'*/
]));
```

I have tested all the other tasks and they all are working properly. When I run `gulp` with this file I get the following output at the `console`

```
[02:31:16] Using gulpfile ~/srs-demo/gulpfile.js
[02:31:16] Starting 'default'...
[02:31:16] Starting 'clean-dist-dir'...
[02:31:16] Finished 'clean-dist-dir' after 9.41 ms
[02:31:16] Starting 'copy-index-file'...
[02:31:16] Finished 'copy-index-file' after 13 ms
[02:31:16] Starting 'expand-file-glob'...
[02:31:16] Finished 'expand-file-glob' after 38 ms
[02:31:16] Starting 'ts-compile'...
[02:31:16] Finished 'ts-compile' after 407 ms
[02:31:16] Starting 'bundle-vendor-pkgs'...
[02:31:16] Finished 'bundle-vendor-pkgs' after 29 ms
[02:31:16] Finished 'default' after 501 ms

events.js:112
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
```

What am I missing in this `gulpfile`? Do I need any other setup besides the `gulpfile`? I am new with `gulp` so, if more information is needed, please ask. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means your js isn't being properly transpiled by babelify.

Try

```
browserify({
    paths: [angularAppLocation+'/node_modules'],
    basedir: '/home/zerocool/srs-demo/loginapp'
})
    .require(deps)
    .transform(babelify.configure({presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]}))
    .bundle()
    .pipe(sourceStream('vendor.bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(angularAppLocation+'/dist'));
done();
};
```

Be sure to download those package dependencies via `npm i --save-dev @babel/core @babel/preset-env`